# Laravel Queue check max attempts

Tags: php, laravel-5

I need a Laravel job to check the max number of attempts the worker is set to try.

```
php artisan queue:listen --tries=3
```

This will try jobs 3 times.  The only thing I can find in documentation for attempts is

```
$this->attempts()
```

This will tell me how many times the job has been attempted, but not the max attempts (from --tries=3).  Is there a method to find out the max attempts?

Answer (score 2):

Try `$this->job->maxTries()`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15522778)

Comment: Not sure what you mean, the method to finding the max attempts is what I provided in the answer: `$this->job->maxTries()`

Comment: Your answer was flagged because of its brief content. Something so brief and without any more value is often posted as a comment rather than an answer. An answer could have done more to educate both the OP and anyone else following up, for example, you could have pointed out the entire [Job API](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Contracts/Queue/Job.htm), etc. OP was clearly looking at docs, just the wrong docs...